# Cancelling/refund a transaction using CyberSource API in .NET

Tags: .net, payment-gateway

I am using the CyberSource API for Payment Gateway. I went through all the documentations that are available and came up with the following code:

1. First I added the service reference to CyberSource using url
   https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.60.wsdl
2. Then I added the following code for making a transaction and then cancelling it. But somehow, cancelling does not seem to work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as there is very little documentation available on the net.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.ServiceModel;
   using PaymentGatewayConsole.CyberSourceTest;

   namespace PaymentGatewayConsole
   {
       class Program
       {
                   private const String MERCHANT_ID = "removed";
                   private const String TRANSACTION_KEY = "removed";
                   private static string REQUEST_TOKEN = string.Empty;
                   private static string REQUEST_ID = string.Empty;

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               MakePayment(); 

               RequestRefund();
           }

   private static void MakePayment()
   {
       RequestMessage request = new RequestMessage();
       request.merchantID = MERCHANT_ID;
       // replace request.merchantReferenceCode with reference number for the current transaction.
       request.merchantReferenceCode = "123";
       request.clientLibrary = ".NET WCF";
       request.clientLibraryVersion = Environment.Version.ToString();
       request.clientEnvironment = Environment.OSVersion.Platform + Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();

       request.ccAuthService = new CCAuthService();
       request.ccAuthService.run = "true";

       BillTo billTo = new BillTo();
       billTo.firstName = "John";
       billTo.lastName = "Doe";
       billTo.street1 = "1295 Charleston Road";
       billTo.city = "Mountain View";
       billTo.state = "CA";
       billTo.postalCode = "94043";
       billTo.country = "US";
       billTo.email = "null@cybersource.com";
       billTo.ipAddress = "10.7.111.111";
       request.billTo = billTo;

       Card card = new Card();
       card.accountNumber = "4111111111111111";
       card.expirationMonth = "12";
       card.expirationYear = "2020";
       card.cardType = "Visa";
       request.card = card;

       PurchaseTotals purchaseTotals = new PurchaseTotals();
       purchaseTotals.currency = "USD";
       request.purchaseTotals = purchaseTotals;

       request.item = new Item[1];
       Item item = new Item();
       item.id = "0";
       item.unitPrice = "49.00";
       request.item[0] = item;

       try
       {
           TransactionProcessorClient proc = new TransactionProcessorClient();

           proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = request.merchantID;
           proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = TRANSACTION_KEY;

           ReplyMessage reply = proc.runTransaction(request);

           REQUEST_ID = reply.requestID;
           REQUEST_TOKEN = reply.requestToken;

           Console.WriteLine("decision = " + reply.decision);
           Console.WriteLine("reasonCode = " + reply.reasonCode);
           Console.WriteLine("requestID = " + reply.requestID);
           Console.WriteLine("requestToken = " + reply.requestToken);
           Console.WriteLine("ccAuthReply.reasonCode = " + reply.ccAuthReply.reasonCode);
       }
       catch (TimeoutException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
       }
       catch (FaultException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("FaultException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
       }
       catch (CommunicationException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("CommunicationException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Method for requesting refund 
   /// </summary>
   private static void RequestRefund()
   {
       RequestMessage request = new RequestMessage();
       request.merchantID = MERCHANT_ID;
       request.merchantReferenceCode = "123";
       request.clientLibrary = ".NET WCF";
       request.clientLibraryVersion = Environment.Version.ToString();
       request.clientEnvironment = Environment.OSVersion.Platform + Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();

       request.ccAuthService = new CCAuthService();
       request.ccAuthService.run = "true";

       //request.ccAuthReversalService = new CCAuthReversalService();
       //request.ccAuthReversalService.run = "true";
       //request.ccAuthReversalService.authRequestID = REQUEST_ID;
       //request.orderRequestToken = REQUEST_TOKEN;
       //request.purchaseTotals = new PurchaseTotals();
       //request.purchaseTotals.currency = "USD";
       //request.purchaseTotals.grandTotalAmount = "10";

       VoidService reqVoid = new VoidService();
       reqVoid.voidRequestID = REQUEST_ID;
       reqVoid.voidRequestToken = REQUEST_TOKEN;
       reqVoid.run = "true";
       request.voidService = reqVoid;

       try
       {
           TransactionProcessorClient proc = new TransactionProcessorClient();
           proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = request.merchantID;
           proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = TRANSACTION_KEY;

           ReplyMessage reply = proc.runTransaction(request);

           Console.WriteLine("decision = " + reply.decision);
           Console.WriteLine("reasonCode = " + reply.reasonCode);
           Console.WriteLine("requestID = " + reply.requestID);
           Console.WriteLine("requestToken = " + reply.requestToken);

       }
       catch (TimeoutException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
       }
       catch (FaultException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("FaultException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
       }
       catch (CommunicationException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("CommunicationException: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);

       }
       Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

In method request refund, i am actually getting the response as Request.ReasonCode = 102 which means an error. Ideally it should be 100. 102 means "One or more fields in the request contains invalid data.".

Help is deeply appreciated...

Comment: Hi Hari, I am trying to user CyberSource also. I have added the web reference, and using the same source code, yet the `TransactionProcessorClient` could not be found. Do you need to reference something to get this namespace?

Comment: Just in case someone is checking this in future (like me): you should be able to find necessary information by logging into the Merchant Board, or by verify the Reply object (should have a field which indicates the invalid fields).

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It works for me.

```
            RequestMessage request = new RequestMessage();
            request.ccAuthReversalService = new CCAuthReversalService();
            request.ccAuthReversalService.run = "true";
            request.ccAuthReversalService.authRequestID = order.Transactionno;
            request.ccAuthReversalService.authRequestToken = order.RequestToken;
            request.purchaseTotals = new PurchaseTotals();
            request.purchaseTotals.currency = "USD";
            request.purchaseTotals.grandTotalAmount = (order.Total).ToString("0.00");
            request.merchantID = MerchantId;
            request.merchantReferenceCode = order.OrderNumber;
            TransactionProcessorClient proc = new TransactionProcessorClient();
            proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = request.merchantID;
            proc.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = Key;
            ReplyMessage reply = proc.runTransaction(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Request Token is not necessary if you're already using the requestId coming from the initial Authorization.
So you can safely remove the line:

```
request.ccAuthReversalService.authRequestToken = order.RequestToken;
```

Also, purchaseTotals.currency is not necessary, through your requestId CyberSource will get that information for you.
Another line saved:

```
request.purchaseTotals.currency = "USD";
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you posted author
You can post a credit amount to users account which will send him/her that money.
To do that you need to specify request.ccCreditService and set it's run field to true.
Same thing can be done in their Business Center UI.

However this has nothing to do with cancelling the actual authorization/settlement transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.ecDebitService = new ECDebitService();
request.ecDebitService.run = "true";

request.ecCreditService = new ECCreditService();
equest.ecCreditService.run = "true";
```

You can use this Credit and Debit service, if end user wants to Debit some amount Eg: $100.00 he can enter - $100.00 and then if the total amount is less than zero you can set Credit service as true and vise versa.

Try this and if u need more help feel free to contact me on mail id.